# Form states API configuration first page load not working

Tags: forms

I would like to show a text field when a checkbox is checked and a specific option is selected in a select list

The form works fine when there are no values in and the form is loaded but doesn't work if I pass in existing values when the form is rendered.

For example if the checkbox is checked and select list item 1 is selected when the form first loads then when I select list item 3 then the the textfield does not show. If I select another option and then select 3 again it does show.

```
 // Get value of field_price_list from current node.
$price_list = $node->get('field_fulfil_price_list')->getValue();
$price_list_enabled = FALSE;
$price_list_value = NULL;
if (!empty($price_list)) {
  $price_list_value = $price_list[0]['key'];
  $price_list_enabled = TRUE;
}

// Switch catalogue on or off.
$form['list_enabled'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => $this->t('Synchronise stock levels with Fulfil.io'),
  '#default_value' => $price_list_enabled,
];

// Select list with FF price lists.
$form['price_list'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select price list'),
  "#empty_value" => "",
  '#options' => [
    '1' => $this->t('Retail'),
    '2' => $this->t('Trade'),
    '3' => $this->t('Create new'),
  ],
  '#options_attributes' => [
    '2' => ['disabled' => 'disabled'],
  ],
  '#value' => $price_list_value,
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="list_enabled"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
    ],
  ],
];

// Label for new item if "Create new" is selected.
$form['new_price_list'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('New list name'),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="list_enabled"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
      ':input[name="price_list"]' => ['value' => '3'],
    ],
  ],
];
$form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

// Change submit label.
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = $this->t('Save');

return $form;
```

Comment: `<select>`'s don't have a `value` have you tried `':input[name="price_list"] option:selected' => ['value' => '3']` instead?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `option:checked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to use condition in the field like this:**

```
$form['new_price_list'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('New list name'),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="price_list"]' => ['value' => '3'],
    ],
  ],
];
```

**Note:** It 'll cover with or without default value scenario, I removed the below additional condition :
**':input[name="list_enabled"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],**

Analysis:
As here you are using already hierarchy of condition
like:
select display only if checkbox field checked
Textfield display only if value 3 selected from select box

But due to adding double condition in your code on textfield ,
Conditional form API logic not work as per expectation specially in case of if default value pass to checkbox